# The system cannot find the file specified in `edx-dl` module

Tags: python, windows, edx

Am trying to use this Python Module. https://github.com/coursera-dl/edx-dl

Please excuse my basic knowledge.

Installed Anaconda 3 Windows 10 then:

`pip install edx-dl`

`pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`

Then to get courses did:

`edx-dl -u user@user.com --list-courses`

`edx-dl -u user@user.com COURSE_URL`

This all worked however once downloads actually started was getting:
Got SSL/Connection error: `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Fiddler showed that it was being blocked by by Cloudfare I suspect due to User-Agent

I the installed Fake_UserAgent https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent and added:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent #added this


def edx_get_headers():
    """
    Build the Open edX headers to create future requests.
    """
    logging.info('Building initial headers for future requests.')

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'edX-downloader/0.01',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
        'Referer': EDX_HOMEPAGE,
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'X-CSRFToken': _get_initial_token(EDX_HOMEPAGE),
    }

    ua = UserAgent()   #added this
    headers['User-Agent'] = ua.ie #added this
```

It then downloaded a pdf and an xls but got another error due to request.py adding a header so added fake to requests.py and commented out the default header as below.

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
        ub = UserAgent()
        self.addheaders = [('User-Agent', ub.ie)] 
        # self.addheaders = [('User-Agent', self.version), ('Accept', '*/*')] [('User-Agent', self.version), ('Accept', '*/*')]
```

The new error is below. I can't work out how to troubleshoot further. I suspect it can't find a file / path possibly due to Windows.

```
[download] https://youtube.com/watch?v=bKkrDLwDnDE => Downloaded\Implementing_ETL_with_SQL_Server_Integration_Services\02-Module_1__ETL_Processing\01-%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s
Downloading video with URL https://youtube.com/watch?v=bKkrDLwDnDE from YouTube.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "edx-dl.py", line 6, in <module>
    edx_dl.main()
  File "c:\edx-dl-master\edx-dl-master\edx_dl\edx_dl.py", line 1080, in main
    download(args, selections, filtered_units, headers)
  File "c:\edx-dl-master\edx-dl-master\edx_dl\edx_dl.py", line 857, in download
    headers)
  File "c:\edx-dl-master\edx-dl-master\edx_dl\edx_dl.py", line 819, in download_unit
    headers)
  File "c:\edx-dl-master\edx-dl-master\edx_dl\edx_dl.py", line 801, in download_video
    skip_or_download(youtube_downloads, headers, args)
  File "c:\edx-dl-master\edx-dl-master\edx_dl\edx_dl.py", line 788, in skip_or_download
    f(url, filename, headers, args)
  File "c:\edx-dl-master\edx-dl-master\edx_dl\edx_dl.py", line 721, in download_url
    download_youtube_url(url, filename, headers, args)
  File "c:\edx-dl-master\edx-dl-master\edx_dl\edx_dl.py", line 761, in download_youtube_url
    execute_command(cmd, args)
  File "c:\edx-dl-master\edx-dl-master\edx_dl\utils.py", line 37, in execute_command
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\anton\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 286, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anton\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\anton\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\anton\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Same issue as here however no resolution or assistance had been provided so thought I would try here instead.

https://github.com/coursera-dl/edx-dl/issues/368

Advice on how to learn to troubleshoot this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Debugged the code and found that couldn't find `youtube-dl`.

Checked echo `%PATH%` and realised I had path to:

`C:...\Anaconda3\` but not to `C:...\Anaconda3\Scripts\ (this is location of youtube_dl.exe)`.

I had added this path but not rebooted.

Rebooted and now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There is another easy solution and no need to use `Fake_UserAgent`, just use other downloaders, like `wget`.

Install fresh edx_dl.

If you are on Windows download [wget](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/), save it for example on H drive.

Change `download_url` function like this:

```
def download_url(url, filename, headers, args):
    """
    Downloads the given url in filename.
    """

    if is_youtube_url(url):
        download_youtube_url(url, filename, headers, args)
    else:
    # jcline
        cmd = (["h:\wget.exe", url, '-c', '-O', filename, '--keep-session-cookies', '--no-check-certificate'])
        execute_command(cmd, args)
```

([Source](https://github.com/coursera-dl/edx-dl/issues/462#issuecomment-386834623))